# Regex for matching text between two regex-patters

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am looking for a way to capture text and its paragraph title from a text document.

Text File:

```
paraTitle-1
--------
Lines and words
empty....
more lines



still part of paraTitle-1

paraTitle-2
--------
Lines and words
empty....
more lines



still part of paraTitle-2
```

I want to capture both the titles and the text below them.

```
 array = [paraTitle-1: <text...below paraTitle-11>,
          paraTitle-2: <text below paraTitle-2>]
```

I made a few attempts with pattern `(?<=(.*))\n----*\n(?=(.*))` to no avail. Any guidance would be awesome.

Comment: will all paragraph's have the same format? i.e: `title-#` ??

Comment: yes. All paragraphs will have `title` followed by a line break `\n` and atleast 6 `-` followed by another line break `\n` and then the para text.

Comment: Try [`(?<title>.*)\R-{5,}\R(?<body>[\s\S]*?)(?=\R.*\R-{5,}\R|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/VDl4N5/1). If line endings are `\n`, use `(?<title>.*)\n-{5,}\n(?<body>[\s\S]*?)(?=\n.*\n-{5,}\n|$)`. You do not have to use named groups, but it seems your language supports them if you need such an array.

Comment: I got [This](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%3FP%3Ctitle%3E%5CS%2B)%5Cn--------%5Cn(%3FP%3Ccontent%3E(%5Ba-zA-Z%20%5Cn%5C.0-9%5D*))&test_string=paraTitle-1%0A--------%0ALines%20and%20words%0Aempty....%0Amore%20lines%0A%0A%0A%0Astill%20part%20of%20paraTitle-1%0A%0AparaTitle-2%0A--------%0ALines%20and%20words%0Aempty....%0Amore%20lines%0A&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) far. I am not sure how to handle potential `-` characters in the text body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex will do:

`(?!--------\R)(.*)\R--------\R((?:\R?(?!.*\R--------\R).*)+)`

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sVczx2/1).

The title separator line (`--------`) can also be specified as `-{8}`, which is easier to adjust to variable length if needed, e.g. instead of exactly 8 dashes, it could be 6 or more: `-{6,}`

Explanation:

- Capture a line of text (paragraph title):

  ```
  (.*)\R
  ```

  - The `.` doesn't match line break characters
  - `\R` matches line breaks, including the Windows CRLF pair. If your regex engine doesn't support `\R`, use `\r?\n` as a simple alternative.
- Make sure the captured text is not the title separator line:

  ```
  (?!--------\R)
  ```
- Skip the mandatory title separator line:

  ```
  --------\R
  ```
- Capture the paragraph text, as a repeating group of lines:

  ```
  ((?:xxx)+)
  ```
- A line has an optional leading line break (first line doesn't have one):

  ```
  \R?.*
  ```
- But make sure the line is not the title of the next paragraph, i.e. it's not a line followed by the title separator line.

  ```
  (?!.*\R--------\R)
  ```